# Modern PHP: can GD be implied?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, php-gd

PHP does not have built-in image editing capability, but many projects use the GD library and the servers I work on have this already installed.

I am distributing an open source product, Camera Life, which lets people manage their photos in a website they run (like Gallery). In there I need to create image thumbnails. Users are running somewhat recent (5.3+) PHP on Mac/Linux/Windows with Apache/IIS or whatever else is popular.

For a stable and modern PHP project, is it best practice to abstract out the image processing functions or hardcode in routines that assume the user has GD installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At concrete5, we simply require they have GD, very rarely do we see anyone who doesn't. Not quite sure that it's best practice, that's just the direction we went.

Best wishes,
Korvin